# How to make two text widgets bottom aligned as shown in the picture in flutter?

Tags: flutter, text

How to make two text widgets bottom aligned as shown in the picture in flutter?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc0HQ.png)

```
child: Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
children: [
  Row(
    children: [
      const Text(
        '\$',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
      ),
      Text(
        '${product.price}',
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

In Flutter, you can achieve this by using the RichText widget, which allows you to display different styles within a single text element. Here's an example of how you can add text containing a dollar sign with different font sizes

```
RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 24.0,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: '\$', // Small dollar sign
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: '100', // Larger amount
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:1.5),
      child: const Text(
        '\$',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),
      ),),
      Text(
        '30.99',
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Two Row Widget. So remove the parent Row and use the child Row as a Parent. Then add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end`. Code:

```
Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Text(
          '\$',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
        ),
        Text(
          '30.99',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Hope it helps!